# Use of external library with interfaces - Error: Cannot declare interface, because the name is already in use

Tags: magento2, interface, code-generation, library

I try to use an external library in my Magento2 module.
The library is the Amazon MWS-PHP Library.

I included the library via composer.json in PSR-0 Format since classnames are in PSR-0 standard (like `Amazon_MarketplaceWebServiceOrders_Client`, etc.).

so my composer.json includes:

```
    "psr-0": {
      "Amazon_MarketplaceWebServiceOrders_":"lib/"
    }
```

and the corresponding folders are `./lib/Amazon/MarketplaceWebServiceOrders/{...}`.

Autoloading seems to work.

If I use "bin/magento setup:di:compile" Magento fails with:

```
Fatal error:  Cannot declare interface Amazon_MarketplaceWebServiceOrders_Interface, because the name is already in use in /var/www/html/magento2/vendor/myvendor/mymodule/lib/Amazon/MarketplaceWebServiceOrders/Interface.php on line 20
```

Why does Magento try to declare an interface?

Is it reasonable to avoid that?
If so, how can I achieve that?

Answer (score 0):

Answer is very simple:

There was another module, that included Namespace in it's composer.json.

So I either could **remove** that module or **use** the namespace without including it in my own module or **rename** my namespace.